# Why does uniform continuity of a function imply that the function is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

As the title states, I'm wondering why:

*If $A$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous on $A$, then $f$ must be bounded on $A$.*

**Proof**:

Since it is uniformly continuous, the function is a Lipschitz function.

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$.

Since $A$ is bounded, $|x-y|$ does not get arbitrarily big and that too is bounded by a constant. Let $|x-y| \leq M$.

Then we have a Lipschitz condition where

$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq LM$.

The function is then bounded by the product of two constants, $LM$, which means that it is bounded. Can someone check this?

Comment: Not each uniformly continuous function is a Lipschitz function. Consider $x\mapsto\sqrt x$. However, this function is still bounded on bounded sets.

Comment: In order to be Lipschitz it must be $C^1$. Now consider that every bounded set of $\Bbb R$ has supremum and infimum$.

Comment: @Dimitris I don't quite get what you mean by $\mathbb{C^1}$ but since $A$ has a supremum and infimum, then in order for $f$ (on $A$) to be uniformly continuous, then $f$ has to also have a supremum and infimum. I can see it in my head but I don't see how to make that leap.

Comment: @Dimitris Lipschitz implies $C^1$, you say? Hardly.

Comment: since $A$ is bounded it's closure is bounded then you can extend $f$ to $\overline{A}$, which is compact, hence it's image is compact.

Comment: @Did No,i say that if $f$ is uniformly continuous and $C^1$ then is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Dimitris: Your first comment reads: "In order to be Lipschitz it must be $C^1$". That means that Lipschitz implies $C^1$, which is not true.

Comment: @robjohn,yes i know.i wrote it wrong. what i wanted to say is my second comment i say that if f is uniformly continuous and C1 then is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there is a constant $M$ so that
$$
|x-y|\le1\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le M
$$
Thus, $f$ is bounded on each interval $[k,k+1]$. Since $A$ is bounded, you can cover it with a finite number of such intervals.

Comment: What is $A{}{}{}$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: from the question: $A$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh right. Is it also true if $A=\mathbb R$ or $A=(-\infty,\infty)$ ? (I guess here $\mathbb R=(-\infty,\infty)$)

Comment: @GinKin: No. That is why it is specified that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: Given $\epsilon$ we can find $\delta$. How are you doing it the other way round?

Comment: Take any $\delta,\epsilon$. The triangle inequality says we can let $M=\lceil1/\delta\rceil\epsilon$.

Comment: will it count as valid proof if we use the theorem :- a function $ f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(a, b)$ if and only if it can be defined at the endpoints a and b such that the extended function is continuous on$ [a, b]$ and since a continuous function on closed bounded interval is bounded we conclude that the uniformly continuous function in open bounded interval is bounded

Comment: @pie: You would need to address the fact that $A$ may not be an interval.

Answer (score 3):

If not $\forall~n\in\mathbb Z^+,~\exists~a_n\in A$ such that $f(a_n)>n.$

$(a_n)_n$ being bounded it has a convergent subsequence $(a_{r_n})_n.$

Thus $(a_{r_n})_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$ which maps to a **non** Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R,$ a contradiction.